# error: no match for 'operator<'

Tags: c++

Tengo un error en mi código, se que se tiene que sobrecargar el operador para entrada y salida pero no se como hacerlo, ¿en qué parte debe ir?.

Si me pudieran ayudar con un ejemplo por favor. El error lo marca en la función `insertaNodo` de la clase `ListaSimple` en la linea `if(v inicio->dameTuDato())`.

Este es el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Termino
{
      private:
              int Coeficiente, Exponente,R;
      public:
             int dameTuCoeficiente();
             int dameTuExponente();
             void modificaTuCoeficiente(int Coeficiente);
             void modificaTuExponente(int Exponente);
             void muestraTusDatos();
             void pideleAlUsuarioTusDatos();
             Termino derivate();
             Termino(int c=0, int e=0);
             bool operator>(Termino derecha);
};
Termino::Termino(int c,int e)
{
    Coeficiente=c;
    Exponente=e;
}
int Termino::dameTuCoeficiente()
{
    cout<<"Ingresa el coeficiente:\n\t";
    cin>>Coeficiente;
    cout<<"\n";
}
int Termino::dameTuExponente()
{
    cout<<"Ingresa el exponente:\n\t";
    cin>>Exponente;
    cout<<"\n";
}
void Termino::modificaTuCoeficiente(int Coeficiente)
{
     this->Coeficiente=Coeficiente;
}
void Termino::modificaTuExponente(int Exponente)
{
     this->Exponente=Exponente;
}
void Termino::muestraTusDatos()
{
     cout<<"Coeficiente ->\t"<<Coeficiente<<"\n";
     cout<<"Exponente   ->\t"<<Exponente<<"\n";
}
void Termino::pideleAlUsuarioTusDatos()
{
     dameTuCoeficiente();
     dameTuExponente();
}
Termino Termino::derivate()
{
     Termino X;
     X.modificaTuCoeficiente(this->Coeficiente*this->Exponente);
     X.modificaTuExponente(this->Exponente-1);
     return X;
}
bool Termino::operator>(Termino derecha)
{
    return this->Exponente>derecha.Exponente;
}

template <class LS>
class Nodo
{
private:
    LS Dato;
    Nodo<LS>* Siguiente;
public:
    Nodo(LS V=0, Nodo* S=NULL);
    LS dameTuDato(void);
    Nodo<LS>* dameTuSiguiente(void);
    void modificaTuDato(LS Dato);
    void modificaTuSiguiente(Nodo<LS> *S);
    void muestraTusDatos(void);
};
template <class LS>
Nodo<LS>::Nodo(LS V, Nodo<LS>* S)
{
    Dato=V;
    Siguiente=S;
}
template <class LS>
LS Nodo<LS>::dameTuDato(void)
{
    return Dato;
}
template <class LS>
Nodo<LS>* Nodo<LS>::dameTuSiguiente(void)
{
    return Siguiente;
}
template <class LS>
void Nodo<LS>::modificaTuDato(LS Dato)
{
    this->Dato=Dato;
}
template <class LS>
void Nodo<LS>::modificaTuSiguiente(Nodo<LS> *Siguiente)
{
    this->Siguiente=Siguiente;
}
template <class LS>
void Nodo<LS>::muestraTusDatos(void)
{
    cout<<Dato<<endl;
    if(Siguiente==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"NULL";
    }
    else
        cout<<Siguiente<<"->";
}
template <class LS>
class ListaSimple
{
private:
    Nodo<LS>* inicio;
    Nodo<LS>* fin;
public:
    ListaSimple();
    ~ListaSimple();
    void insertaNodo(LS v);
    void borraNodo(LS v);
    void muestraTusDatos(void);
    bool vacia(void);
    bool buscaDato(LS v);
};
template <class LS>
ListaSimple<LS>::ListaSimple()
{
    inicio=fin=NULL;
}
template <class LS> //ERROR POR LA SOBRECARGA DE DATOS (función miembro)
void ListaSimple<LS>::insertaNodo(LS v)
{
    if(vacia())
    {
        inicio=fin=new Nodo<LS>(v);
    }
    else
    {
        if(v<inicio->dameTuDato()) // Error.
        {
            inicio=new Nodo<LS>(v,inicio);
        }
        else
        {
            if(v>fin->dameTuDato())
            {
                fin->modificaTuSiguiente(new Nodo<LS>(v));
                fin=fin->dameTuSiguiente();
            }
            else
            {
                Nodo<LS> *adelante,*atras;
                atras=adelante=inicio;
                while(adelante->dameTuDato()<v)
                {
                    atras=adelante;
                    adelante=adelante->dameTuSiguiente();
                }
                atras->modificaTuSiguiente(new Nodo<LS>(v,adelante));
            }
        }
    }
}
template <class LS>
void ListaSimple<LS>::borraNodo(LS v)
{
     Nodo<LS> *adelante,*atras;
     if(!vacia())
     {
         adelante=inicio;
         while(adelante!=NULL && adelante->dameTuDato()<v)
         {
              atras=adelante;
              adelante=adelante->dameTuSiguiente();
         }
         if(adelante==inicio&&v<inicio->dameTuDato())
         {
              cout<<"El dato: "<<v<<" no esta en la lista\n";
         }
         else
         {
             if(adelante!=NULL && adelante->dameTuDato()>v)
             {
                  cout<<"El dato: "<<v<<" no esta en la lista\n";
             }
             else
             {
                 if(adelante==NULL)
                 {
                     cout<<"El dato: "<<v<<" no esta en la lista\n";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(inicio->dameTuDato()==v)
                     {
                           inicio=inicio->dameTuSiguiente();
                           delete(adelante);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if(adelante==fin)
                         {
                              atras->modificaTuSiguiente(NULL);
                              fin=atras;
                              delete(adelante);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             atras->modificaTuSiguiente(adelante->dameTuSiguiente());
                             delete (adelante);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
template <class LS>
void ListaSimple<LS>::muestraTusDatos(void)
{
    Nodo<LS> *aux;
    aux=inicio;
    while(aux!=NULL)//while(aux)
    {
        cout<<"-> "<<aux->dameTuDato()<<endl;
        aux=aux->dameTuSiguiente();
    }
}
template <class LS>
bool ListaSimple<LS>::vacia(void)
{
    return inicio==NULL;
}
template <class LS>
ListaSimple<LS>::~ListaSimple()
{
    if(!vacia())
    {
    Nodo<LS> *aux=inicio;
    while(aux!=NULL)
    {
        inicio=inicio->dameTuSiguiente();
        delete aux;
        aux=inicio;
    }
        inicio=fin=NULL;
    }
}
template <class LS>
bool ListaSimple<LS>::buscaDato(LS v)
{
    Nodo<LS> *aux=inicio;
    int x=0;
    if(!vacia())
    {
        while(aux!=NULL&&!x)
        {
            if (aux->dameTuDato()==v)
            {
                x=1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(aux->dameTuDato()!=NULL)
                    aux=aux->dameTuSiguiente();
                else
                    return x;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"La lista esta vacia\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    system("color F5");

    Termino T1(1,3),T2(-5,2),T3(2,1),T4(3,0);
    //if(A<B)
    //if(A>B)

    T1.derivate();

    ListaSimple <Termino> L1,L2;
    L1.insertaNodo(T1);
    L1.insertaNodo(T2);
    L1.insertaNodo(T3);
    L1.insertaNodo(T4);
    L1.muestraTusDatos();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: intenta con if(inicio->dameTuDato() > v)

Comment: Gracias @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, me dejo de marcar el error pero ahora se presenta en otra linea, en el cout

`void ListaSimple<LS>::muestraTusDatos(void)
{
    Nodo<LS> *aux;
    aux=inicio;
    while(aux!=NULL)//while(aux)
    {
        cout<<"-> "<<aux->dameTuDato()<<endl;
        aux=aux->dameTuSiguiente();
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a analizar la instrucción que produce tu error:

```
if(v<inicio->dameTuDato())
   ~ ~~~~~~
```

Estamos comparando que `v` sea menor que lo que devuelve el método `dameTuDato` de `inicio`, averigüemos qué son cada uno de ellos:

`v` es una instancia del tipo del parámetro plantilla de `ListaSimple`:

```
void ListaSimple<LS>::insertaNodo(LS v)
```

`inicio` es un puntero a la plantilla `Nodo`:

```
Nodo<LS>* inicio;
```

`dameTuDato` es un método de la plantilla `Nodo` que devuelve una instancia del tipo del parámetro de dicha plantilla:

```
template <class LS>
class Nodo
{
public:
    LS dameTuDato(void);
};
```

Es decir, se está comparando si una instancia de `LS` es menor que (`<`) otra instancia de `LS`. ¿Qué es `LS` en este contexto?

```
ListaSimple <Termino> L1,L2;
```

El tipo con el que se instancia la plantilla es `Termino`, por lo tanto `LS` es `Termino` y ésta clase carece de operador menor que (`<`):

```
class Termino
{
private:
    int Coeficiente, Exponente,R;
public:
    int dameTuCoeficiente();
    int dameTuExponente();
    void modificaTuCoeficiente(int Coeficiente);
    void modificaTuExponente(int Exponente);
    void muestraTusDatos();
    void pideleAlUsuarioTusDatos();
    Termino derivate();
    Termino(int c=0, int e=0);
    bool operator>(Termino derecha);
};
```

#### Solución(es).

Puedes añadir el operador a la clase:

```
class Termino
{
private:
    int Coeficiente, Exponente,R;
public:
    int dameTuCoeficiente();
    int dameTuExponente();
    void modificaTuCoeficiente(int Coeficiente);
    void modificaTuExponente(int Exponente);
    void muestraTusDatos();
    void pideleAlUsuarioTusDatos();
    Termino derivate();
    Termino(int c=0, int e=0);
    bool operator>(Termino derecha);
    bool operator<(Termino derecha); // <--- Nuevo
};
```

O puedes cambiar la comparación:

```
if(inicio->dameTuDato()<v)
```